# React AG Grid - How to customize tool panel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using Enterprise AG Grid in our react application. I could not find anything on below in official docs of Ag Grid.

1. How can we hide all columns at once, not using column api but user should be able to do it, may be a hide all check box in tool panel?
2. Is there any way to customize tool panel? So that we can add more options specifically for #1.
3. Once we hide all the column and then add it back from toolpanel. Is there a way that we can force new column to be added in the last instead of its original position as per coldefs?

Any help is appreciated, apologies for long text here.

Update 1.

I was able to add workaround for #1, by using Grouped columns and setting groupheaderheight to 0. Added all columns in one group and then a check/uncheck for all is available in tool panel.

Update 2:

Most of it is supported by Ag-Grid now. Please refer their latest build.

Comment: If your questions have been answered, please post an answer so it will help the community

Comment: PratikBhat - Added reference, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these features are supported by AG-Grid (latest build) out of the box (except #3, which is very  specific to our application). Please refer AG-Grid's documentation for more details:

[Tool Panel Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/)